# Problems with installing XVector package

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

I have problem with installing R package XVector. 
I've tried to install it using biocLite:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XVector’ in 
dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object 
'/home/fedorovaad/R/XVector/libs/XVector.so':
/home/fedorovaad/R/XVector/libs/XVector.so: undefined symbol:egzrewind
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

Also I used R CMD INSTALL XVector_0.16.0.tar.gz (the same error). 
Besides I remove old version of Xvector (the same error...)

How can I fix it?